# Maximum adb device connections

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, adb

I’m trying to have more than 16 emulators running on Windows 11 Pro, via Android Studio latest version.

I’ve set a System variable for:

ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT

with a value of

9999

restarted the PC but still I cannot launch more than 16 emulators.

Is there anything else I need to do ?

Comment: What's the error when you launch the 17th?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set `ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT` environment variable or you haven't set it correctly.

If you follow along [this](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:tools/acloud/list/instance.py;l=863?q=ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT) method you will realize that the default maximum number of adb instances corresponds exactly to 16:

```
_DEFAULT_ADB_LOCAL_TRANSPORT_MAX_PORT = 5585
_EMULATOR_DEFAULT_CONSOLE_PORT = 5554

(5585 + 1 - 5554) // 2 = 16
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer ! I tried to set it both on osx and on windows but I couldn't create more then 16 emulators in Android Studio. What did work was to create emulators on the command line, separately. They have separate UI from Android Studio (although they appear in the avd list). For anyone stumbling on the post here's what I created the 17'th and so forth emulator:

./emulator -port 6000 -avd avd_name

And Voila ! I repeated with ports 6002, 6004 and so on and created the supplemental emulators needed.

Comment: please describe how you set the env variable